# Custom Response from Controller in Finatra

Tags: scala, finatra

In my app I have a custom case class as below with a bunch of additional fields.

```
case class User(id: UUID, username: String, password: String)
```

Now my Finatra controller picks up the response as returned by the service and sends a JSON response which contains the password hash as well. The controller is as basic as it gets

```
get("/users") {request: GetUsersRequest =>
    userService.users()
}
```

So my question would be how do we customize this response such that I can drop the password field and add some additional data as well.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `userService.users()` returns a list of users. i.e. `List[User]` then transform the response with `map`.

For example, you can map to a new case class.

```
case class UserDTO(id: UUID, username: String, comment: String)
```

You can also `map` to a `Tuple` if you don't want use a class just yet.

```
get("/users") {request: GetUsersRequest =>
    userService.users().map(u => UserDTO(u.id, u.username, "Comment!"))
}
```

Comment: So this works. But I was wondering if there is a more Scala-y way to do this. Since Finatra implicitly converts a response of type Future[T] to a json object of T, if we could ask it to make that the json object with the fields we want.

Comment: That is exactly what the above answer does. Particularly as you asked for additional information too. In principle, changing the set of fields is changing the type of data, so indeed what you do is going from Future[T] to Future[U].